# eclipse-BIRT Master-Page Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, report, global-variables, birt

I'm using the 2.3.2 version of eclipse birt.

I want to put a value that comes from the database in footer master-page. But, the problem is i can't use like: dataSetRow["customer"].
As i've searched birt forums, in the current version i'm using of birt isn't possible to use variables as well.

So i tried globalvariable.
It shows in the master-page, but with a null value.

Reason:
The master-page get the globalvariable value from the method "initialize" but the data i want to set in the globalvariable is in the "fetch" method. Does anybody know how to workaround?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a more current version of BIRT?

Comment: Yes, the client uses that version of birt, the template is builded in that version and i can't upgrade it. They say that their environment does not support greater version of birt. Any idea?

Comment: You might want to try here http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/ for a solution.  There may not be a lot of experts on working around old issue at SO.

Comment: yeah, already tried that with no success. I thought here i might get any lucky. Thanks anyway.